# Slick 3: How to construct dynamic filter with optional column?

Tags: scala, filter, slick

I need to construct dynamic filter based on some criteria which involves
optional column:

**Criteria**

```
case class Criteria(
  name: Option[String] = None,
  description: Option[String] = None,
)
```

**Table mapping**

```
class OrganizationsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[OrganizationModel](tag, "organizations") {
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def description: Rep[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("description")

    def * = (id, name, description) <> ((OrganizationModel.apply _).tupled, OrganizationModel.unapply)
  }
```

**Filter**

```
organizations.filter { model =>      

  List(
    criteria.name.map(model.name.like(_)),
    criteria.description.map(v => model.description.isDefined && model.description.like(v))
  )
  .collect({case Some(cr)  => cr})
   // value && is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[_1]
  .reduceLeftOption(_ && _).getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
}
```

But I'm getting compilation error:

> value && is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[*1] [error]
>
>   .reduceLeftOption(* && _).getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])

If I add `get`  to `model.description`  like this:

```
criteria.description.map(v => model.description.isDefined && model.description.get.like(v))
```

it compiles fine, but throws runtime exception:

> slick.SlickException: Caught exception while computing default value
>   for Rep[Option[_]].getOrElse -- This cannot be done lazily when the
>   value is needed on the database side

How to build dynamic query in slick which involves optional column?

Answer (score 2):

This is a utility I use in a project at work:

```
implicit class OptionFilter[E, U, C[_]](query: Query[E, U, C]) {
  import slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition
  def optionalFilter[O, T <: Rep[_]](op: Option[O])(f:(E, O) => T)(
    implicit wt: CanBeQueryCondition[T]): Query[E, U, C] =
      op.map(o => query.withFilter(f(_,o))).getOrElse(query)
}
```

Usage

```
criteria.optionalFilter(model.description)(_.description.? like _)
```

Essentially it applies the filter to a query if the target value (e.g. `model.description`) is defined, otherwise it just returns the original query.

Comment: Looking at the variable names in the question, you answer code appears confusing. Could you provide surrounding code to clarify what "criteria" and "model" are in your example?